# kprefix in \krddefinekeys seems to be not optional

Tags: optional-arguments, key-value

Maybe I misunderstood something but the following example doesn’t compile with out a optional argument defining the `kprefix`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{keyreader}

%   [KV]------\/
\krddefinekeys*{CL}[my]{%
   cmd/test//;
}

\krdsetkeys{CL}{test=x}

\begin{document}
\mytest
\end{document}
```

It stops with the error text

```
! Package xkeyval Error: Key 'test' undefined in families 'CL'.
```

But if one inserts the `[KV]` it works. Is this optional argument mandatory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks. It isn't due to a bug as such but something I didn't foresee. I will upload a revised version immediately. In the meantime please use the following patch of `\krddefinekeys`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{keyreader}
\makeatletter
\protected\def\krddefinekeys{%
  \begingroup\endlinechar\m@ne
  \krd@testst{\@testopt\krd@d@finekeys{KV}}%
}
\makeatother

\krddefinekeys*{CL}[my]{%
   cmd/test//;
}
\krdsetkeys{CL}{test=x}
\begin{document}
\mytest
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works. Thanks for the fast response :-)